# How to troubleshoot a Xamarin Forms iOS app crashing in TestFlight?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an app that I have been working on for several months, running it on multiple simulators and three physical iPhone devices (iphone 6 plus, iphone 12 and iphone 13).

When forcing an app to close via the relevant **double click home button**/**swipe up** -> **swipe out** gestures the app has always closed without complaint.

Now after deploying the app to the app store and testing it via TestFlight on my three iPhones, two of them only (iphone 12 and 13) crash with an error message.

> "MyApp" Crashed - Do you want to share additional information with the
> developer?

My questions:

- Why is this suddenly appearing now?
- How can I investigate and troubleshoot the problem?
- When I choose **Share** the 'additional information', where is this information being sent. I have checked my account and relevant email addresses and can't find it.

Comment: Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs).  Additionally, using a crash reporting tool like appcenter.ms or raygun.io can be very helpful as they will capture managed crash reports, where Apple only provides you with native reports

Answer (score 0):

I found the "additional information" regarding the crash report.

It is stored in **App Store Connect** -> **MyApp** -> **TestFlight**, on the left hand column **Feedback -> Crashes**.

Also implementing **appcenter.ms** as suggested by Jason in his comment above helped me track down why my app was crashing.

Case closed.